# CSES Problem Set: Introductory Problems - Number Spiral [New Approach]

Tags: c++

Logic: So, I am thinking that for every coordinate I get, I will find its corner coordinate. For example, if I'm given (2,5), I will get the value of (5,5). This is simple. The value at the (n,n) coordinate is n^2 - n + 1.

Let's say we are given the coordinate (n,m). Value = Value at (n,n) or (m,m) depending on which is bigger + (n-m). So final formula at any given coordinate is (n^2 -n + 1) or (m^2 - m + 1) + n -m

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long long square(long long x) { return x * x; }

int main() {
    
    long long number_of_tests;
    cin >> number_of_tests;

    while (number_of_tests--) {
        long long row, column, value;
        cin >> row >> column;
        value = ((row >= column) ? (square(row) - row + 1) : (square(column) - column + 1)) + (row - column);
        cout << value << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Number Spiral Problem](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1071/):
[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnOsK.png)

The last input of test #1: 956420707 85755464 should give output 914740566951293900.
But with my code, I'm getting 914740568692624386.

I tried to do it manually and I was getting 914740568692624386 as output. What do you think is the error here? How to fix it?

Comment: Your formula is wrong. Think about what happens depending on whether `max(row, column)` is odd or even.

Comment: What is a CSES and why should we care?

Comment: Hint:  Use a 2d array or vector, and fill it with your spiral.  After fill, you can print.  Simplifies the printing process.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Not sure if you saw the problem statement, but x and y can be up to 10^9, so that is 10^18 cells of a uint64_t. That will not fit in the 512MB (5*10^8) allotted.